# Setup ASP.NET MVC 4 Routing for any URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm currently experiencing problem with setting up routes in ASP.NET MVC 4.

I'm trying to build system with the ability to add pages with custom routes.
For example, user can add new page and set it's URL to `/about-us`, and every page created like this should execute `PagesController` action `GetPage` with parameter URL.

I have tried to comment defaults in default URL, and then I have setup `{*url}` to go to `new { controller = "Pages", action = "GetPage", url = UrlParameter.Optional }`, and this seams OK, but when I try to get action link using `@Url.ActionLInk("Index", "Home")` I get exception.

I have managed to resolve also that by adding `{*url}` route at the end, but now I'm experiencing problem with URLs with multiple parameters like `/company/about-us`. When requesting URL I get exception `The resource cannot be found`, and I know that is because I have route with the url: `{controller}/{action}`.

So is there a solution to get those URLs to my Controller beside handling it with Error Handler for 404.

This is my current `RouteConfig.cs` file:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}"
            //defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "simple",
            url: "{controller}/{action}"
            //defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "empty",
            url: "",
            defaults: new { Controller = "Home", Action = "Index"})
        ;

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Pages",
            "{*url}",
            new {controller = "Pages", action = "GetPage", url = UrlParameter.Optional}
            );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to have a catch-all route, as you do, and then pass the `url` to the GetPage method as a parameter and use that to load and serve your dynamic content.

Regarding the `{controller}/{action}` route, this take precedence because it appears *before* your catch-all route. If you want to support your pre-defined pages and the custom pages, one will need to have a unique identifier in the URL such as a prefix on the path. Perhaps if you want all of your company routes to be served statically at /company/xxx, create a route as such:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Company Pages",
    url: "company/{action}"
    defaults: new { controller = "Company" }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`@Url.actionlink` creates link based on routes defined in Routeconfig. so ... if your only concern is with that link than , u can use `html.actionlink or html.routelink` where u can directly give route name.. as in answer , if u want all your anonymous call redirect to single controller then u can use **David Haney**'s solution that , u can also use constraints ... if still that does satisfy your needs then u can use custommvchandler

http://beletsky.net/2011/06/inside-aspnet-mvc-route-to-mvchanlder.html
https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/asp.net-mvc-routing-extensibility/
http://geekswithblogs.net/sankarsan/archive/2009/01/18/developing-custom-routehandler.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are creating some kind of "CMS" tool.

You should create a custom Route Handler.

And in that route handler, you do a simple check if you have any Pages with the current url, if so update the RequestContexts Controller and Action properties to the Pagecontroller and the Action you want, and you can also pass the page id then you are done.

See my answer on this post.
[Database selection before routing in ASP.Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26333966/database-selection-before-routing-in-asp-net-mvc/26334396#26334396)

Hope this helps!