# Encrypt Url in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In MVC C# I want encrypt the URL Controller name and View name.
Every time user login, the url should be different.

I need to change this:

```
http://localhost:6065/Home/index
```

to this:

```
http://localhost:6065/aghef54df/sdf54512
```

This encrypted text should change if the user login next time.

I have tried to change the `routeconfig` like this

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default1",
        url: RandomString() + "/" + RandomString() + "/{rowid}/{operation}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", rowid = UrlParameter.Optional, operation = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

The `RandomString()` will generate a random string.

But this does not change when user login next time. Is there any way to get the sessionid and encrypt it and display in url?

Or is there any other way without changing `routeconfig`?

Comment: url: "/{rowid}/{operation}",
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", rowid = RandomString(), operation = RandomString() } you have to do something like this. I don't know MVC exactly. But basic idea is just give to your rowid and operation RandomString values. Your route was something like: asdfasfasd/bhubibuj/somevalueforrowid/somevalueforoperation

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following stack overflow answer. It does not *directly* answer your question but explains the process you will need to create your own route handler. You will need to extract the action and controller values, decrypt them (using your own key?), and then add them back to the RequestContext so route handling can occur. Hope this helps!

[Database selection before routing in ASP.Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26333966/database-selection-before-routing-in-asp-net-mvc)